# Logger for Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: logging, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I couldn't found any loggers for windows 10 universal app, i have tried out log4net, Microsoft enterprise library, Nlog but none of them are supported in windows 10 Universal platform.

Can anyone suggest me good logger for the windows 10 UWP?

Comment: NLog supports UWP with NLog ver. 4.5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried MetroLog? You can install it using NuGet:

```
Install-Package MetroLog
```

Here's an quick example:

```
using MetroLog;
using MetroLog.Targets;

LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, new FileStreamingTarget());

ILogger log = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<MainPage>();

log.Trace("This is a trace message.");
```

You can find a tutorial explaining how to add it on your project at http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/11/adicionando-logs-em-universal-apps. Also there is an explanation regarding retrieving these logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @talkitbr

Comment: Meanwhile `FileStreamingTarget` became obsolete. `StreamingFileTarget` is advised instead.

Comment: you can use application insights as an option. i think that uwp apps comes with AI as default.

Answer (score 15):

### [Serilog](https://serilog.net/)

One possibility is to use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) as an central logging interface and configure it to have an Sink that works with UWP.

You can use one of the many [Sinks you can choose from](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks), but you can also opt to use your own logging infrastructure by implementing a custom sink.

To make it even more useful, you can use [Anotar.Serilog.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Anotar.Serilog.Fody/) to use the [Fody Code Weaver](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and use Aspects to make your logging trivial.

Typically you want to use a central logging provider for Application Lifecycle Management (ALM), as well as a local sink (File) as fallback for fatal errors.

#### [MetroLog](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog)

[MetroLog](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog) is a simple logging infrastructure on top of ETW and LocalState. This is fast and easy to implement, but it does not help you with ALM, since centralized logging is not supported.

#### [UWP Logging](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging)

[Universal Windows Plattform Logging](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging) is relatively new and only possible with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. You can choose between ETW and LocalStorage. It gives you most low-level-control about how your log should look like, but naturally also causes the most work to implement and also lacks ALM capabilities.

#### Helpful Links

- [Strategies for Handling Errors in your Windows Store Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/10/16/strategies-for-handling-errors-in-your-windows-store-apps/)

Comment: Used Metrolog before. Until I have problem getting logs from device. Switching to Serilog.

Comment: What sink are you using with Serilog and UWP? I can't get any output from it.

Comment: Unfortunately, console logging is pretty much useless. I use Serilog primarily to write to an remote logging store (Logstash/Elasticsearch; Seq and RayGun are really good options too). In the future Microsoft.Azure.Mobile will be another option. 

Ideally, you use Serilog as your main logging layer and implement a custom sink for local logging output on top of MetroLog or UWP Logging, so that you can configure which logging output should target the remote log and which one should target the local one.

If you don't want to write a sink. you can also consider Serilog.Sinks.Observable.

Comment: Used Metrolog before, faced error related to FileLoadException File in use errors.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to log to a file and take advantage of the Microsoft's lightweight DI framework you can use Serilog.

In Nuget Package Manager Console enter the following:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
Install-Package Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File
```

Set up dependency injection container at the composition root. In our case it is OnLaunched method in the App.xaml.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Windows.Storage;
...

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
     ...
    // Create IOC container and add logging feature to it.
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddLogging();

    // Build provider to access the logging service.
    IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // UWP is very restrictive of where you can save files on the disk.
    // The preferred place to do that is app's local folder.
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    string fullPath = $"{folder.Path}\\Logs\\App.log";

    // Tell the logging service to use Serilog.File extension.
    provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().AddFile(fullPath);
    ...
}
```

Once set up, logging is very simple. Just inject the logger into your class.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class MyClass
{
    readonly ILogger<MyClass> logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        logger.LogInformation("Hello from MyClass.");
    }
}
```

Your log file should be created in:

C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\f15fdadf-faae-4f4a-8445-5feb195ff692_68newbw0j54vy\LocalState\Logs\App-20171206.log,

where f15fdadf-faae-4f4a-8445-5feb195ff692_68newbw0j54vy is the package name from the Package.appxmanifest file in my solution.

Please note that AppData folder is hidden in File Explorer by default.

And here is its content:

```
2017-12-06T17:06:33.1358005-06:00  [INF] Hello from MyClass. (25278b08)
```

Comment: How to Inject Logger in class, when MyClass instance is called ?

Comment: Logger injection is handled automatically for you by IOC container. services.AddLogging() in the OnLaunched method above tells the IOC container to inject logger into MyClass for you when MyClass is instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I know is to use the APIs in windows.foundation.diagnostics namespace to do ETW tracing.

And Microsoft has provided a sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/Logging).

Comment: how to read the log message? I've tried the FileLoggingSession example, and view with wpa.exe, I can only see the event in Graph Explorer, but the Diagnostic Console is not showing the LogMessage

Comment: while event tracing is a sort of logging, it is different that logging. 

Event tracing is used to observe the execution and performance of an application and it is possible to turn it on and off at any time on demand. It generates a lot of data quickly, so it is disabled by default. 

Logging is something that is always active and should be used for security (ie. a user is logging in and off, access to secured resources, etc.) and stability (ie. exceptions an application crashes). Because of its security concern, it must be always active.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard Serilog rolling file sink in UWP, you just need to tell the logger where to log to. Here's some code to set that up (I'm using Autofac);

```
private static void RegisterLogger(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    const string fileOutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
    var logPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Logs", "MyAppName-{Date}.log");

    var logConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                            .WriteTo.RollingFile(logPath, outputTemplate: fileOutputTemplate);

    Log.Logger = logConfiguration.CreateLogger();

    builder.RegisterLogger();
}
```

```