# C# Logger for UWP Application with Microsoft IoT

Tags: c#, logging, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I tried to write a thread safe logger for my UWP Application in C# which runs on a Raspberry Pi with Microsoft IoT but I have no idea where to begin. I tried creating a file in the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` but the operations are all async and I can't await them in the lock body of my log method.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do it is use nuget to install MetroLog or [Serilog](https://serilog.net/)

MetroLog is a good way to log.

To use MetroLog that you should install MetroLog.

You can install MetroLog in nuget.

[image]

It's easy to use and you can see this link below.

[Building a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Application (Part 4) – Logging w/ MetroLog - Intertech Blog](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/building-a-universal-windows-platform-uwp-application-part-4-logging-w-metrolog/)

Comment: okay I used Serilog and set it up like it was told [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) but sadly it does not create a log file or the directory! I got the path while debugging and watching the variables of the logger. Sadly I don't get an exception either! Any help?

Comment: @ReVoluti0n_ MetroLog  is easier to use than Serilog.

Comment: @lindexi, have you looked at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886613/logger-for-windows-10-uwp-app)?Hope that is helpful for you.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Thx

Comment: @lindexi okay I got it working. It was a authorization problem. I used a relative path where my UWP Application had no rights to write files. Now I am using `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and it's working fine, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I was using log4net until time came to start doing Windows App Certification Kit compliance and it failed miserably.  If you intend to use _Microsoft Store_, knowing exactly what is going into your app is paramount.  I decided to write my own.  Using non-Microsoft NuGet packages is arguably a recipe for disaster